# localStorage keys is not deleted after called from useEffect and cause Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 routes that I don't want to allow access to an logged user.

```
/login
/forgot-password
```

In those Component I've applied `useEffect` function to detect if the user is "logged in" like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(isLogged()){
      history.push("/dashboard")
    }
  }, [])

export const isLogged = () => {
    return (
        localStorage.getItem("userid") !== null ||
        localStorage.getItem("authUser") !== null ||
        localStorage.getItem("token") !== null ||
        localStorage.getItem("permission") !== null
    )
}
```

Now if the user is logged in it's move to `/dashboard`

on `/dashboard` I check the user authentic with API request to the server, and if the data is not valid I redirect the user to `/logout`

```
useEffect(() => { //act like componentDidMount()

        getInstitutes().then((response) => {
            if (response.errorCode !== null && response.errorName !== null) {
                if (response.errorCode === 999) { //invalid token so... logout please.
                    props.history.push('/logout')
                } else {
                    setErrorMsg(response.errorName)
                    setErrorNum(response.errorCode)
                }
            } else {
                setInstitutesList(response.object)
            }
        }).catch((e) => {
            setErrorMsg("Error occur.")
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])
```

On `/logout` -

```
useEffect(() => {
    clearStorage();
    history.push("/login")
  })
```

`clearStorage()` function:

```
export const clearStorage =  () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("userid")
        localStorage.removeItem("authUser")
        localStorage.removeItem("token")
        localStorage.removeItem("permission")
    }
```

And then I receive this error, which say that I'm in infinite loop, this cause because of the `localStorage` items are not delete at all, And that cause the infinite loop.

I don't have any clue why the localStorage's items does not deleted this way,

when I enter the route `/logout` manually it's successfully delete the items.

What is my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

didn't you forget to pass the dependency array in the /logout path?

```
useEffect(() => {
    clearStorage();
    history.push("/login")
}, []) // <--- here
```

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view, this logic should not be a part of the component, you could have it inside the auth hook that you get the isLogged from, or you could have it inside your route component.
Just add a prop that specify the access level of this route and have the logic there.

Should not be a part of the component itself by any chance.